# Django Rest framework : passing queryset to Response()

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am using django rest framework in my application.In view, for get query , I am getting list of models in form of queryset and trying to pass to my Response()

organizationViews.py

```
 def get(self,request):
    user = self.request.user
    result = OrganizationModel.object.all()
     serializer = OrganizationSerializer("json", list(result), many=True)
     return Response(serializer, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

organizationModel.py

```
class OrganizationManager(models.Manager):
    def create_organization(self, _name):
        org = self.model( name = _name)
        org.save(using=self._db)
        return org


class Organization(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(_('organization'), max_length=100,       blank=True,unique=True)

def as_json(self):
    return dict(
        id=self.id,
        org_name=self.name)

object = OrganizationManager()

class Meta(BaseModel.Meta):
    db_table = 'organizations'
    verbose_name = _('organization')
    verbose_name_plural = _('organizations')

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

I am getting following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/Users/richagupta/VirtualEnvs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 174, in get_response
 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/richagupta/VirtualEnvs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 172, in get_response
response = response.render()
  File "/Users/richagupta/VirtualEnvs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 160, in render
self.content = self.rendered_content
File "/Users/richagupta/VirtualEnvs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/response.py", line 71, in rendered_content
ret = renderer.render(self.data, media_type, context)
File "/Users/richagupta/VirtualEnvs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 104, in render
separators=separators
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 237, in dumps
**kw).encode(obj)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
return _iterencode(o, 0)
File "/Users/richagupta/VirtualEnvs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/utils/encoders.py", line 64, in default
 return super(JSONEncoder, self).default(obj)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/json/encoder.py", line 180, in default
 raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
 TypeError: OrganizationSerializer('json', [<Organization: zeotap>, <Organization: movial>, <Organization: Redbull>, <Organization: mogey>, <Organization: vizury>], many=True):
id = IntegerField()
name = CharField() is not JSON serializable
```

If I do following in get call :

```
serialized_q= json.dumps(list(queryset), cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
return Response(serialized_q, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

I don't get the error, but result is something like following :

```
 "[{\"id\": 1, \"soft_delete\": false, \"created_at\": \"2016-04-14T13:35:21.636Z\", \"name\": \"org1\", \"updated_at\": \"2016-04-14T13:35:21.636Z\"}, 
  {\"id\": 4, \"soft_delete\": false, \"created_at\": \"2016-04-14T13:37:02.230Z\", \"name\": \"org2\", \"updated_at\": \"2016-04-14T13:37:02.230Z\"}]"
```

How should I pass queryset to Response method ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really want to override the get method, you would probably be better off overriding get_queryset;

```
class ViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Model.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ModelSerializer

    def get_queryset(self): #this method is called inside of get
        queryset = self.queryset.filter(doyourfiltering=True)
        return queryset
```

You can just return a queryset here straight up, Django will serialize it for you. You'll have access to the request through self.request.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can only use a serializer to serialize a single model. So instead of:

```
serializer = OrganizationSerializer("json", list(result), many=True)
```

Try:

```
data = [
    OrganizationSerializer(model).data
    for model in result
]
```

Then just:

```
return Response(data)
```

See: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#serializing-objects

Comment: Sorry, try that instead

Comment: That still give following : "[{\"id\": 1, \"soft_delete\": false, \"created_at\": \"2016-04-14T13:35:21.636Z\", \"name\": \"org1\", \"updated_at\": \"2016-04-14T13:35:21.636Z\"}, 
{\"id\": 4, \"soft_delete\": false, \"created_at\": \"2016-04-14T13:37:02.230Z\", \"name\": \"org2\", \"updated_at\": \"2016-04-14T13:37:02.230Z\"}]"

Comment: That looks potentially right to me... What output are you expecting?

Comment: That's just escaping the " that appears in the JSON string - I'm not sure what you're doing to see the information this way, but that looks like a valid JSON string to me. If you were to print it, for example, you wouldn't see the \s

Comment: No I am using rest client to test my api. So as response I am getting below. Means somewhere I m converting string / dict to JSON so above way is not correct . 
"[{\"id\": 1, \"soft_delete\": false, \"updated_at\": \"2016-04-14T13:35:21.636Z\", \"created_at\": \"2016-04-14T13:35:21.636Z\", \"name\": \"org1\"}, {\"id\": 4, \"soft_delete\": false, \"updated_at\": \"2016-04-14T13:37:02.230Z\", \"created_at\": \"2016-04-14T13:37:02.230Z\", \"name\": \"org2\"}]"

Comment: Hang on, are you trying to return a django rest framework Response object in a normal django handler? Why are you not defining a ViewSet object and attaching it to a router?

Comment: Using viewset, I am not able to customize my API response, error message,  status code etc. Can you give me example how can I do that in view set. I am new to python and django so may be i m missing something.

Comment: You can customise all those things with a viewset. I suggest you work through the tutorial.